# How to create a table in a existing database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

I'm trying to create a table in an existing database using SQL Server and VB.NET. But, when executing the code, I get a error. It looks like a permissions error since the POS_DB exists, and I use it elsewhere in my project through the same connection.

I can not use (`trusted_connection=true`) since clients are accessing the database through SQL Sever authentication via a network.

Can someone advice me, how to resolve this.

```
    Public connString As String = "Data Source=SQLSERVER\SLMA;Database=POS_DB;User Id=sa;Password = xxxxxxxxxxxxx;" 'global connection string
```

> Error : The specified schema name "POS_DB" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

Following is the code I use to create the table. (dbName is a variable which holds the database name)

```
Private Sub cmdCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCreate.Click
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Close()
    End If
    conn.Open()
    Dim obj As SqlCommand
    Dim strSQL As String
    obj = conn.CreateCommand()
    strSQL = "CREATE TABLE " & Trim(dbName) & ". ST_BOOK (" &
      "Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " &
      "Entry  VARCHAR(30), " &
      "entry_date DATETIME, " &
      "item_name VARCHAR(50) " &
      ") "
    ' Execute
    obj.CommandText = strSQL
    obj.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is with `"CREATE TABLE " & Trim(dbName) & ".ST_BOOK (" &` change it to `"CREATE TABLE " & Trim(dbName) & ".dbo.ST_BOOK (" &` 
See the `.dbo.` The order is like this: [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[ObjectName]

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts No, don't do that. The connection should determine the current database to be used for the application's queries. Do NOT use 3 part names without a good reason and understanding the consequences. And why assume DBO is the correct schema?

Answer (score 0):

The comment posted by Preben Huybrechts, works.

The problem is with

```
"CREATE TABLE " & Trim(dbName) & ".ST_BOOK (" & change it to "CREATE TABLE " & Trim(dbName) & ".dbo.ST_BOOK (" & See the .dbo.
```

The order is like this:

```
[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[ObjectName] – Preben Huybrechts
```

Answer (score 0):

So the Error:

> Error : The specified schema name "POS_DB" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

gives the following information "POS_DB" is used as a Schema name.

Your code concatenates the database name on the place the schema name is expected.

`"CREATE TABLE " & Trim(dbName) & ". ST_BOOK (" &`

Should be
`"CREATE TABLE " & Trim(dbName) & ".dbo.ST_BOOK (" &`

Or using `..` because dbo is the default schema.

`"CREATE TABLE " & Trim(dbName) & "..ST_BOOK (" &`

The order is like `[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[ObjectName]`

ObjectName = The name of the table,view,stored procedure, function, index, ...

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite your code as follow:

```
Private Sub cmdCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCreate.Click
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Close()
    End If
    conn.Open()
    Dim obj As SqlCommand
    Dim strSQL As String
    obj = conn.CreateCommand()
    strSQL = "CREATE TABLE ST_BOOK (" &
      "Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " &
      "Entry  VARCHAR(30), " &
      "entry_date DATETIME, " &
      "item_name VARCHAR(50) " &
      ") "
    ' Execute
    obj.CommandText = strSQL
    obj.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

**NOTE 1:**

Because you have mentioned the database name in connection string, you do not need to mention it inside your code again, and your scripts will be executed against your database by default.

**NOTE 2:**

When creating table, if you do not mention the Schema of the table, the table will be created by default on database user's default schema. If you do not want to create the table using default schema, then you need to concatenate the schema name plus a dot with table name too(`CREATE TABLE MySchema.ST_BOOK...`). Obviously you have to create a schema named `MySchema`(`CREATE SCHEMA MySchema`), before you want to create the table